# How to make IHttpActionResult interact with MVC 5 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

After a long couple of projects in which I had to focus in other technologies I am reconnecting with MVC.

I created a test solution with an MVC 5 project and a Web Api 2 one.

On the Web Api controller I am returning an Ok result with the content I get from the business layer something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllActivities()
{
    return Ok(activitiesBl.GetAllActivities());
}
```

And the MVC controller is doing the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = activitiesService.GetAllActivities();

    return View(result);
}
```

Now this does not work since the variable result is of type IHttpActionResult which is not what the view is expecting as a model. In order to get the content of that result I need to do something like:

```
var content = ((System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Model.Activity>>)result).Content;
```

which looks weird and at some point the Web Api controller might have cases in which it might return another instance of IHttpActionResult like NotFound or something so that cast would not work and I don't think is a good idea to be testing all possibilities in the MVC controller since that would couple both controllers and that would be the case for all actions which is not very DRY.

So the questions are:

1. How should the interaction between the two types of controllers be implemented?
2. Should I forget about returning IHttpActionResult from the Web Api action and just return the expected model?
3. If I cannot return IHttpActionResult wouldn't that limit the use of the Web Api to the one MVC project instead of being available to different clients?

Comment: Is `activitiesService` by any chance an instance of your `ApiController`?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How should the interaction between the two types of controllers be implemented?

It shouldn't. Having an MVC controller wrap an API controller is fundamentally flawed. You're *bending* your design into making it DRY, but that'll only bring you more pain.

If you want to expose your data as both a webpage and an API, then have both controllers call your business layer to retrieve the model (e.g., `activiesBl`), and then construct the views, each in its own way.